# Dynamically generate a single new drop down menu in a html form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a html form defined . I have a button for the user to select his occupation . If his occupation happens to be a student then i need to generate another new button dynamically . If the user selects anything other than a student then i dont want any new button . I am unsure how to do . Do i use jquery ? I have no idea to use jquery . Can some one help ? Any pointers

Thanks.

```
<?php

?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#occupation').change(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == 'Student')
        {
            $('#school').show();
        } else {
            $('#school').hide();
        }
    });
});


</script>

<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>


<form>

<select name="occupation" id="occupation">
    <option value="">- Select Occupation -</option>
    <option value="Worker">Worker</option>
    <option value="Student">Student</option>
</select>
<select name="school" id="school" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select School Type</option>
    <option value="4 Year">4 Year</option>
    <option value="2 Year">2 Year</option>
</select>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So i wrote this sample test program exactly the way i was asked to but it does not work . the new div field namely school does not start showing when i select Student from the drop down menu .. Cant see the problem . Once i get it working here then i shall try putting it in my code . Any help most appreciated.

Comment: Ok so i got it running .  if($(this).val() returns an index and not a string . So the correct comparison should be if($(this).val() == "0") if 0 in the drop down list corresponds to the Student .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I accomplish this by placing the additional form element in the HTML, simply hidden like so:

```
<select name="occupation" id="occupation">
    <option value="">- Select Occupation -</option>
    <option value="Worker">Worker</option>
    <option value="Student">Student</option>
</select>
<select name="school" id="school" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select School Type</option>
    <option value="4 Year">4 Year</option>
    <option value="2 Year">2 Year</option>
</select>
```

Then you can use JS, as I prefer jQuery, to show the div or hide the div when applicable:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#occupation').change(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == 'Student')
        {
            $('#school').show();
        } else {
            $('#school').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: your code makes alot of sense . However i think i am doing some mistake .

Comment: your code surely makes a lot of sense to me . However i am unable to get it running . I am highly unfamiliar with JS debugging so its tougher . The thing that is happening is that the school div element is not displayed when i select ``Student`` from the occupation field . Rather the title i give to the school div element gets displayed only after i click the "Save" button on the page .. Well i want dynamic updation as soon as ``Student`` is selected in the box .

Comment: Ok so i got it running .  $(this).val() returns an index and not a string . So the correct comparison should be if($(this).val() == "0") if 0 in the drop down list corresponds to the Student . Then it works

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery would simplify this:

Let's say you have the following:

```
<form>

  <select name="occupation">
      <option value="Non-Student">Non-Student</option>
      <option value="Student">Student</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Then the following would be used to append the button if the user selected 'Student':

```
$(function(){
    $('select[name="occupation"]').change(function(){
      var val = $(this).val();
      if(val=='Student'){
         $('form').append('<button>New Button</button>');
      }
    });
});
```